# Axios with basic auth

Tags: node.js, axios

I have this function:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const https = require('https');

exports.apiRequest = async ({url, method = "GET", body}) => {

    const URL = process.env.APP_API_URL + url;
    const USER = process.env.APP_API_USER;
    const PASS = process.env.APP_API_PASSWORD;

    const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      });

    try {
        const config = {
            method: method,
            url: URL,
            auth: {
                username: USER,
                password: PASS
            },
            body: body,
            httpsAgent: httpsAgent 
        }
        
        let res = await axios(config);
        //console.log(res);
        return res.data;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
}
```

so I call it:

```
const { apiRequest } = require('./api/petition.controller');
const { urlEvents,
        getEventsFilterDate } = require('../utils/events/api/apiRoutes');

// GET Events
exports.getEvents = async (req, res) => {
    const data = await petition({
        url: urlEvents.getEvents,
        method: 'GET',
        body: {}
    });
    console.log("DATA:  ", data);
    return data;
}
```

currently I'm getting nothing, I test witn postman the `URL` with basic auth and work, but with node js and axios didn't work, what's wrong??

the function apiRequest  is the component, I just want to structure for method get, post, put and delete.

Comment: Your parameter is called url, not URL. You have to change it in your config.

Comment: I changed in ```const URL = process.env.APP_API_URL + url;```

Comment: Have you tried to log the `config` before passing it to the axios? Has it all the expected values?

Comment: yes I did it!, and get right data.